# Running NLP on Heroku

Tags: heroku, nlp, stanford-nlp

If you use Heroku, you know Heroku imposes slugsize limit of 300MB. Our company is trying to run NLP app, which, using Stanford NLP library, is more than 300MB.

Is there anyone who has successfully hosted Stanford NLP process on Heroku? How did you achieve it? If you had to lose the weight by excluding parts of NLP library, how did you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size problem your having is caused by the model files in stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar. You do not need to keep all the files in stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar to use the toolkit.  I would suggest assessing what functionality you want to maintain for your server and then remove the models that are not required for that functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Wouldn't removing models cause exceptions or in lower accuracy?

Comment: If task A loads model B, if you have model B it will work.  If you remove model B it will crash.  You just need the models that the tasks you care about use.

Comment: I mean the best thing to do is run the code with no models, it will crash.  Just keep adding files until the crashes stop, and then you will have the minimal set.  I think the models you need will print out as it loads for the most part, so you should keep the ones you see loading in the print out probably.  But ultimately if the code runs and doesn't crash, it means you have all the models you need.

Comment: I was able to include just the models we are loading. I wasn't the NLP engineer, so it took a bit to realize we're loading models one by one. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: How would one go about including only certain models?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you need so much space is that the models are big. You can use smaller models if your task permits it. To achieve that you will need to retrain them on a subset of the training data and perhaps exclude some fancy features or use a more narrow context window.

The alternative would be to compress the models and when you need them uncompress and keep them in memory while your app is running. That is probably a bad idea though. Maybe you should consider using a different NLP system.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem before. I talked with Heroku support and they increased my slack size to 500 Mb. So, I would suggest to talk to them. Also, heroku has recently added support for docker deployment. You can try using CodeShip or other CI with docker deployment to try out. I believe that bypasses their custom CI/CD completely. 
Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the version 3.5.0. It's lesser than 300M but still i got problems. I think the memory is not enough for free heroku sand-box.

Comment: Yes as i thought:


» 22 Jan 2016 01:21:46.944 2016-01-22 09:21:46.564335+00:00 app web.1 - - Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: Hmm my team is happy to get higher-tier to run NLP, so we're doing fine when we change dyno to one of the Performance ones. We find that we need at least 1.5GB to run NLP. I'd like to optimize this greatly, because we're hitting 1.5GB running just one NLP process at a time..